# How does one convert $y=x-x^2$ into $x=f(y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $y=x-x^2$, how does one convert this into $x=f(y)$ format?

Comment: Hint: Complete the square.

Comment: Note that $y = 0$ both when $x = 0$ and when $x = 1$, so $x$ cannot be a function of $y$. The best we can do is solve for $x$ in terms of $y$ under a suitable restriction (for example, $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: it is not a 'one to one function ' ,so it has not a reverse function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to solve this eqation:

$x^2-x-y=0$. So $$x=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4y}}{2}$$

However, $x=f(y)$ may be not a function since it is one-to-more.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
y&=x-x^2\\
x^2-x+y&=0\\
x&=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4y}}{2}\end{align}$$